# Call javascript function after form validation ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have set an `OnSubmit()` property to `@Html.BeginForm()` that calls this function:

```
    $('form').submit(function () {
        deleteImages();
        return true;
    });
```

The problem is, this gets executed even if the form isn't valid. How do I check if the form is valid, then call the function?

Answer (score 0):

You can try ubobtrusive validation (if you are using Jquery)

```
$('form').removeData("validator").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));
if ($('form').valid()) {
  deleteImages();
  return true;
}
```

This might help.

Comment: Isn't this only client side validation?

Comment: Yes you are right. It is a client side validation.

Comment: emm...what if the user deletes that part and submits it?

Comment: In that case you might get an error. So I guess you can use conditional statement which checks that part is deleted or not and perform submit event.

Comment: But I cant just send the whole html to the controller. How would I check? Can you be more clear?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the logic in your application, but if you are afraid of someone messing with you JS, then you should do validation on the server as well (Its always better to have validation on both - client and server side)! Validate it on the server and return a flag or something, then you will know that you have to execute deleteImages()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).